# Missing solutions of a matrix congruence

Tags: equation-solving

There are [some indications](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330351/reconstruct-a-matrix-from-its-traces) that the following matrix congruence might have a one-dimensional family of solutions. Also [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78106/solving-a-quadratic-matrix-equation) is relevant

```
a = DiagonalMatrix[{5, 4, 3}]
b = DiagonalMatrix[{3, 4, 5}]
X = Array[x, {3, 3}]
r = NSolve[
  Transpose[X].a.X == b && (Transpose[X].X)[[1, 1]] == 
    1 && (Transpose[X].X)[[2, 2]] == 1 && (Transpose[X].X)[[3, 3]] == 
    1, Flatten[X], Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
```

This is clearly a solution

```
X={{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{1,0,0}}
```

I am curious if there are other real solutions. However, MA cannot find even the obvious one. Suggestion of experts how to obtain these (preferably the whole family) solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your expression to remove the equalities (which are hard for real-valued equations) and represent it as a minimization problem. This gives an answer without trouble:

```
NMinimize[
 Norm[Flatten[{Thread[Transpose[X].a.X - b], (Transpose[X].X)[[1, 1]] - 
     1, (Transpose[X].X)[[2, 2]] - 1, (Transpose[X].X)[[3, 3]] - 1}]], Flatten[X]]
```

Comment: In contrast to Solve, the Minimization method is quite stable. It was unexpected to me.